# How to disable/enable Microsoft Security Essentials from the command line?

Tags: anti-virus, ms-security-essentials

I would like to know how to disable and enable Microsoft Security Essentials from the command line.

This is a common procedure on build machines in order to speed-up the build process.

Comment: +1 on the fact that you explained **why** you want to do it.

Comment: Or else we would have though he was making a virus.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To disable from the (elevated) command line:

```
net stop MsMpSvc
```

To start from the (elevated) command line:

```
net start MsMpSvc
```

However, you may get similar results by simply going in to the configuration and disable scanning on your solutions/build folder

Comment: I'm getting "System error 5 has occurred. Access is denied." (I ran command prompt as admin).

Comment: Hi @BornToCode - if you are running as an admin, and, your machine doesn't have multi admin levels/domain with further restrictions, this should work... I have a busy day, but, my contact details are in my profile - feel free to send me an email and I can take a quick look for you later to see if anything weird is going on/see if there is something I can do quick.