# Stopping Microsoft Security Essentials

Tags: windows-7, windows, anti-virus, ms-security-essentials

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/83066/how-to-disable-enable-microsoft-security-essentials-from-the-command-line) used to work. However after a recent Windows Update it is no longer possible neither to use net stop command nor the services applet to stop this service.

It also seems not possible to use either sc config or the services applet for disabling the service.

How this can be resolved?

Comment: They did this so malware cannot easily disable it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Microsoft Security Essentials and go to the "Settings" tab. Click "Real-time protection" and uncheck "Turn on real-time protection (recommended). Save changes. This should disable the real-time protection service.

Comment: This is as far as it will allow you to disable it without uninstalling it completely. If you go to the "Microsoft Antimalware Service" under services.msc, the stop option is disabled.

Comment: Well, it not used to be like this until recently. How do you uninstall it?

Comment: Go to "control panel," "uninstall a program", select "Microsoft Security Essentials" and click "uninstall."

Answer (score 0):

Hit the windows key or click the start button, open control panel and "add/remove programs" you should be able to find it either of those along with a option to uninstall/remove it.